# Facebook Picture to Google App Engine Application (Java)

Tags: java, facebook, google-app-engine

If users of appengine application can login using their Facebook account, is it possible to transfer some pictures of the user from their Facebook account to appengine application?

What will be the steps in doing such thing? Just give me some hints and references. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get the facebook id of the user then getting the profile picture is easy.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{id}/picture
```

Everything else requires auth_token.

Read more about graph api and FQL at developers.facebook.com.

Comment: its only the profile picture, how about other picture and save it in appengine application?

Comment: For accesing user photo you require user permission. If that is not an issue go ahead a try facebook graph api.